# URLのパラメータを判別して期間限定のページを出し分ける方法

Tags: javascript

表題の件について質問になります。

期間限定のページを運用で回していきたいと思っていて、
URL末尾に`?enddate=200731` のようなパラメータをセットして、このパラメータを判別してページの表示期間を
制御させる方法（記述）をご教示頂けますと幸いです。

この例で言うと２０年８月１日になった時点でページが見れなくなる想定です。

それか、パラメータに有効期間をセットして、その有効期間を判別してページを出し分ける方法のどちらかの方法が知りたいです。。。

何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 本質的ではないのですが質問内容を素直に解釈するとその例で示されているもの（特定の日付まで見れる）はURLを閲覧者がいじることで任意に変えられてしまいませんか？

Comment: webを、大きく分けてサーバー側と、クライアント側と考えた場合、クライアント側の技術で厳密に制限をかけるのは、簡単に破られる可能性が高いです。それを気にしなければ、javascriptで

Answer (score 0):

とりあえずパラメータを探し出してYYYYMMDDの形式に直してみましょう。以下がそのコードです。

```js
if (0 != document.location.search) { //パラメータの存在の確認
    var parameter = document.location.search.substring(1).split('&');//パラメータを取得した後?を取り除いて&で区切ったリスト
    for (var i = 0; i < parameter.length; i++) { //リストの要素の数(=パラメータの数)を取得しその回数分繰り返す
        var parameta_sub = parameter[i].split('='); //それぞれのパラメータを名前と値で分離
        if (parameta_sub[0] == 'enddate') { //パラメータの名前がenddateだった場合のみ実行
            console.log('20'+parameta_sub[1]); //YYMMDD形式なので20を追加しYYYYMMDD形式にし出力(このコードだと2000年~2099年しか使えませんが実用十分かと思います。)
        }
    }
}else {
    console.log(null); //パラメータが存在しなかった際にnullを出力
}
```

この後は詳細が記されていないのでよくわかりませんがif文で分岐を入れてあげればいいと思います。